# Kotlin override fun with subtype

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin, kotlin-generics

Im having trouble inheriting an interface containing a method/fun of a base type, that i would like to override as a subtype in the class implementing it.

So far i have the interface

```
interface IModel {
    fun convert(dataModel: BaseDataModel)
}
```

And the class implementing it:

```
class SettingsModel: IModel {
    override fun convert(dataModel: BaseDataModel) {
        // Conversion of models here

    }
}
```

And i also have the SettingsDataModel which is:

```
class SettingsDataModel: BaseDataModel() {
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is for every class/model implementing IModel, being able to get the specific DataModel, like:

```
class SettingsModel: IModel {
    override fun convert(dataModel: SettingsDataModel) {
        // Conversion of models here

    }
}
```

without needing to cast it. I guess i cant because it modifies the signature of the fun making it not a real override. I tried using generics and [generic constraints](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints) but no luck:

```
interface IModel {
    fun <T :BaseDataModel>convert(dataModel: T)
}
```

but its not working. Any work around for this?

Comment: Side note: you can't restrain function params (because then someone who uses a interface's implementation couldn't use it) but you can be more specific about your return type (e.g.: in interface return is `Any` but you can in impl do `Int`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
interface IModel<T : BaseDataModel> {
    fun convert(dataModel: T)
}

class SettingsModel: IModel<SettingsDataModel> {
    override fun convert(dataModel: SettingsDataModel) {
        // Conversion of models here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I guess i cant because it modifies the signature of the fun making it not a real override

You're right, this is not possible: **Kotlin**, *same as Java*, does not allow *covariant method arguments*. Two methods `fun foo(n: Number)` and `fun foo(I: Int)` would be considered "overloads" instead of "overrides".

You should go use generics. See an example [here](https://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/24-java-lang/482-covariant-parameter-types.html).